# Setting ImageView bitmap shows nothing

Tags: android, bitmap, uri, android-imageview

I'm using following codes to take a picture. The token picture will be saved but setting its URI or Bitmap shows nothing. How can I solve this problem?

**Note:** Following codes are some methods and an overridden method.

```
public static void takePicture(Activity activity) {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(activity.getPackageManager()) != null) {
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = Images.createTempFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Logger.log(activity, e);
            }
            if (photoFile != null) {
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                activity.startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, Constants.RequestCodes.IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            }
        }
    }

public static Uri getUriFromFileName(String fileName) {
        return Uri.fromFile(new File(fileName));
    }

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (requestCode == Constants.RequestCodes.IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            addViewToContainer(Images.getUriFromFileName(Logged.General
                    .getTempTakePhotoFilePath()));
        }
}

private void addViewToContainer(Uri result) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        Uri uri = result == null ? Images.getUriFromFileName(Logged.General
                .getTempTakePhotoFilePath()) : result;
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplicationContext()
                    .getContentResolver(), uri);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Logger.log(this, e);
        }

        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams
                .MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        mContainerLayout.removeAllViews();
        mContainerLayout.setForeground(null);
        mContainerLayout.addView(imageView);
    }
```

Comment: How many megapixels is the camera? If the camera is more than 8 MP then your phone might be running out of memory to process it onto an ImageView.

Comment: @WisdmLabs That's exactly the reason. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hi  Try This.....

```
private void openCamera() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH_mm_ss");
    String currentTimeStamp = dateFormat.format(new Date());
    f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), currentTimeStamp);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            try {
                String click = f.getAbsolutePath();


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

And now u get File PAth of acptured image then

```
    File imgFile = new File(iv_path);

            if (imgFile.exists()) {

                myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
                iv_prpfile.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
                iv_back.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
            }
```

Happy coding :-)